# How to Encrypt / Decrpyt files present in HDFS with GPG Encryption

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, encryption, gnupg

I want to write job(Either in Spark/JAVA) that should perform encryption and decryption the files present with in HDFS it self with out copying back to local by using GPG.

I have Others public key to encrypt the file and My private key to decrypt the files from others.While encryption input file is .gpg format and while decrypt output file should be .gpg

Any Suggestions and code is helpful

Answer (score 1):

We actually have production processes that do write encrypting with PGP.
The way you can do it is setting the encryption codec.
Unfortunately, AFAIK, there's no ready to use codec for PGP/GPG.
You can use this one: https://github.com/spotify/hadoop-openpgp-codec, but beware that it states it is not complete and it should not be used for production. 
We actually used it as a starting point and wrote our own all in Scala for spark. Unfortunately, it was done for work and I cannot share it.
You'd also have to add the logic to manage the keys. We use it to encrypt only, so we just bundle the public keys, but in order to decrypt, you'll have to manage the security of your private key.

One you have your codec ready and compiled in your spark job, you can have spark automatically encrypt and decrypt with something like:

```
    context.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "true")
    context.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec", "com.spotify.hadoop.openpgp.OpenPgpCodec")
```